# Veins and SUMO: assigning multiple module types to a vehicle or including pedestrians inside a vehicle

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using Veins 5.1 and might be forced to keep it. I would like to have multiple (2) different OMNeT .ned modules to be assigned to a single SUMO vehicle. 2 modules with the exact same mobility pattern and departure time are needed.

According to the comment ( line 132 and following in TraCIScenarioManager.cc ) only a single module type can be assigned to a vehicle type.
Could this be changed?

I think an alternative solution would be to have 2 passengers ride the vehicle and assign a module type to each of them.
I tried the following:

```
<vehicle id="0" type="non" route="1" depart="0"/>
<person id="p0" type="ue1"  depart="triggered">
    <ride to="1/1to1/2" lines="0"/>
</person>
<person id="p1" type="ue2"  depart="triggered">
    <ride to="1/1to1/2" lines="0"/>
</person>
```

The passengers do show up when running the SUMO simulation with sumo-gui but do not get assigned a module type in the OMNeT simulation. The code in the omnetpp.ini is correct. A vehicle would get assigned the correct module type.

Would it be possible to include the passengers?

I tried having 2 vehicles with identical routes and departure times, but that caused SUMO to create a delay between the 2 vehicles and does not seem to be an option.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a workaround:

INET provides an AttachedMobility module.
The one module that uses VeinsInetMobility can create the other module and the newly created module can then use AttachedMobility.